# Firebase UI Email Link signin intent extra is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The following 3 functions are used to set up email and other auth checks (called in order)

```
    private void buildSignInIntentBuilder() {

        ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setAndroidPackageName(getString(R.string.packageName), true, null)
                        .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                        .setUrl(getString(R.string.dynamic_link_url))
                        .build();

        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder()
                        .enableEmailLinkSignIn()
                        .setActionCodeSettings(actionCodeSettings)
                        .build(),
                // new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setRequireName(false).build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder()
                        .build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder()
                        .build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder()
                        .build());

        signInIntentBuilder = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.icon_forget_me_not_1);
    }

    private void catchEmailLinkSignIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intent: " + getIntent().getExtras());
        if (AuthUI.canHandleIntent(getIntent())) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
                return;
            }

            String link = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ExtraConstants.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN);
            Log.d(TAG, "link: " + link);
            if (link != null) {
                signInIntentBuilder.setEmailLink(link);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createCheckAndSigninListener() {
        // set firebase sign in listener
        mAuthStateListner = firebaseAuth -> {
            // Already logged in
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "user already signed in");
                // Check user even if signed in to register him to database (if haven't)
                FirebaseAuthHelper.getInstance().checkRegisterUser(user, this, CHECK_USER_DB);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "user hasn't signed in");
                // Signed out or hasn't logged in
                startActivityForResult(
                        signInIntentBuilder
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN
                );

            }
        };
    }
```

I have set up a dynamic link with firebase hosting. And being able to redirect into the same activity upon clicking the received email link.

However,

```
String link = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ExtraConstants.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN);
Log.d(TAG, "link: " + link); // --> produces "link: null"
```

Shows despite successfully getting a intent, there is no `EMAIL_LINK_SIGNIN` extra in the `getExtras()`. I spend few hours looking into the source code of FirebaseUi, but I didn't find where the constant `EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN` is used and how is the intent from dynamic link parsed.

Any idea how to fix this problem is appreciated. I had already spent a whole day trying to figure this out.

Comment: I found it out, use intent.getresult.tostring instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `String link = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ExtraConstants.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN);`
 use `getIntent().getData().toString();` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it is no longer relevant to me. I just checked the newer documents on FireBaseUI https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth. The official documentation is now updated to use `String emailLink = intent.getData().toString();` (So the document is wrong/outdated when I was reading it). Instead of `String emailLink = intent.getExtras().toString();`. Can you confirm if both of them works or only the `getExtras` works?

Comment: What do you mean by both of them? Also, could you please accept the answer so that other readers can see the solution.

Comment: Please check the link above for the email auth. It uses `.getData()` instead of `.getExtra()`. Your answer currently conflicts with the official documentation. I just want to double-check before accepting.

Comment: I have tested with both, and I can confirm that they both work on my device. But i have still updated the answer to fit the official documentation